# How do I include files for my sever in __sapper__ build in Svelte / Sapper

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, svelte, sapper

I am currently attempting to include a server middleware called Parse in my sapper server that is configured in `sapper-project/src/server.js`.

```js
express().use('/api', const api = new ParseServer({
    databaseURI: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
    cloud: __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
    appId: 'myAppId',
    masterKey: 'masterKeyTest', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
    serverURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
}))
```

It takes a mandatory property called cloud which takes a path string that imports server script files for cloud functions. When the sever is built `__dirname` refers to the generated `__sapper__` directory. Problem is I do not know how to include `/cloud/main.js` in the build result of Sapper.

I get this error as wherever I put `/cloud/main.js` as its not included in the `__sapper__` build file.

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/username/Developer/sapper-project/__sapper__/dev/server/cloud/main.js'
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. The rollup plugin copy ("rollup-plugin-copy") copies paths at build time. Here is my solution:

```
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy'
export default {
    client: {...}
    sever: {
        ...
      plugins: [
        copy({
            targets: [
                { src: 'src/cloud', dest: '__sapper__/build/server' }, 
                { src: 'src/cloud', dest: '__sapper__/dev/server' }
             ]
         })
      ]
   }
}
```

Hopefully it's not a problem when going into production.